# DataTables wrong sorting on some columns?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using the JQuery plugin Datatables and it's not sorting as it should, the first columns are sorting fine, but everything else is sorting wrong. When I try to sort the column "length" I get an error. Test it yourself : http://ppaddict.com/tests.php
they are all int or double and in phpmyadmin I have no problems sorting them.
length is "time" tho.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "serversideTests.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "bProcessing": true,
      "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": [0],
      "sClass" : "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [1],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [2],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [3],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [4],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [5],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [6],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": null,
      "bSortable" : false,
      "sClass" : "aligncenter",
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return full[4] + ' - ' +
            full[5] + ' [' + full[6] + ']' +
          '<br><a href=' + 'http://osu.ppy.sh/d/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Download' + '</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": [7],

      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [8],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [9],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [10],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }, {
      "mData": [11],
      "sClass" : "aligncenter"
    }], "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']]
  })
})
```

I am using the server-side example from DataTables just a little bit modified :

```
    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "setid" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? /* <a href='$aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]'><img src='http://s.ppy.sh/images/osu-download-direct.png'></a>*/
           '<a href=\'http://osu.ppy.sh/s/'.$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]].'\' target=\'_blank\'><img height=\'100\' witdh=\'100\' src=\'http://b.ppy.sh/thumb/'.$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]].'l.jpg\' alt=\'N/A\'></a><a href=\'osu://dl/'.$aRow[ $aColumns[$i]].'\'><img height=\'100\' witdh=\'100\'  src=\'http://s.ppy.sh/images/osu-download-direct.png\'></a>'  : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }

            else if ( $aColumns[$i] == 'length' ) 
            {
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? 


date('i:s',strtotime($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]))   : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];

            }


            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

datatable sort by first column by default

you can change default ordering by add `aoColumns`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
            { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc", "asc" ] },
            { "asSorting": [ "desc" ] },
            null
        ]
    } );
} );
```

or you can sort by defined column

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand you correctly, but my problem is, when I try to sort by some columns it doesn't give me 1|2|3|4|5 it makes them 3|2|5|1|2